# Cause: executing external native build for cmake

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn and open it with android studio. But when i try to build it I get error how can i fix this?

```
Cause: executing external native build for cmake /home/krullis/kod/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring project ':main'.
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring project ':main'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':main'.
... 62 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: executing external native build for cmake /home/krullis/kod/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueHandlerImpl.reportIssue(SyncIssueHandlerImpl.kt:53)
at com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueReporter$DefaultImpls.reportError(EvalIssueReporter.kt:122)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueHandler$DefaultImpls.reportError(SyncIssueHandler.kt)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueHandlerImpl.reportError(SyncIssueHandlerImpl.kt:30)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.build(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:203)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$7(BasePlugin.java:818)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:806)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you solve it?